# Generating NFT with random attributes?

Tags: tokens, random

I'd like to create a contract that generates an NFT for the caller (purchaser) that contains some randomness to it.

Are there any examples someone could point me to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tezos doesn't provide any randomness though Michelson currently. PVSS features are expected to come in future proposals which can enable randomness generation.

Currently, the best solution is probably to use an oracle(decentralized or not) to achieve the necessary randomness.

Comment: Thanks, any pointers to oracles that can do this? I've heard that Chainlink was getting involved in Tezos somehow, is that something that is ready or still too early?

Comment: It is still early, we are currently working on the bridge which should be ready in a few weeks.

But you can find a good guide here: https://github.com/anonymoussprocket/CryptonomicExamples/tree/master/TezosChainlinkOracle